# MongoDB Database stats

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a db (MongoDB) where every few minutes I store temperatures (it has over 20k entries right now). And I would like to display some statistics about this data on my website (Running on Node.js/Express + Mongoose).

Now I would like to calculate some statistics (avg, max, min, ...) and display them on my website. Currenly I loop through all the entries in front-end (javascript) which slows everything.

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share an attempt at solving the problem with us!

Comment: Like I said I tried going through all the entries and calculating everything manually using javascript which slowed down the website a lot. I'm not asking for an exact algorithm but for an idea of how to do that without slowing down the website.

I thought maybe calculating all the averages every time new data comes in but I thought there might be even better solution.

Comment: Look into aggregations with min,max, and avg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the best way is to have a pre-aggregated document. This document is updated at the same time as when you insert new data into your "main" collection.

Using your example, if you only need avg, max, and min, you can create a document like:

```
{
  max: <max value seen so far>,
  min: <min value seen so far>,
  avg: <avg value seen so far>,
  sum: <total value seen so far>,
  n: <number of data points seen so far>
}
```

Note that to be able to calculate a new average, you would need the `sum` and `n` fields in the document above. You update this document every time a new data is inserted, using the new [MongoDB 4.0 transactions feature](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) if you're worried about atomicity.

After this, finding the min, max, avg is simply a single `find()` command to display the content of this document.

See [Hierarchical Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/hierarchical-aggregation/) for a more complex example of this idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!